# How to identify the number 0 as zero and not as an even number

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Complete noob. Just wanna log the number 0 as zero and not even.

```js
var num = 0

if (num % 2 !== 0) {

  console.log("odd")

} else if (num % 2 === 0) {

  console.log("even")

} else if (num == 0) {

  console.log("zero")

} else {

  console.log("error")
}
```

I expect the output to be "zero" but it keeps logging it as even.

Comment: You're testing whether it's even before you're testing whether it's 0.

Comment: I figured lol, just got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because if else if and else run top down, if it meet a condition, it will ignore other condition.

You can move the else if zero up like this.

```js
var num= 0

if (num % 2 !==0){

    console.log("odd")

} else if (num == 0){

    console.log("zero")

}
else if (num %2 ===0){

    console.log("even")

}  else {

    console.log("error")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code you are testing num%2===0 before num==0 that's why you are getting the 'even' as your output try like this and your code will work fine :)

```
 var num= 0

if (num % 2 !==0){

    console.log("odd")

} else if (num == 0){

    console.log("zero")

}  else if (num %2 ===0){

    console.log("even")

}else {

    console.log("error")
}
```